# Creating a computed(possibly hidden) column using COLLATE SQL

Tags: sql, collate

I'm using SSMS 18.

I have a column with 500,000,000 records that are codes. Those codes begin with a number of  characters, that represent an object, followed by random characters.
For example:

AZ4658 & TU874U = A-Z

sd8udf & kl8udf = a-z

0huoer & 0huoer = 0

3bhlbc &   3jhkla = 3

5bfdsg & 5byfdu = 5

9nbgyc & 98cnjj = 9

In my 'WHERE' clause, I have:
WHERE [Code_Records] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN Like '[A-Z]****'
or
WHERE [Code_Records] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN Like '[a-z]****'
or
WHERE [Code_Records] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN Like '[0]****'
or
WHERE [Code_Records] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN Like '[3]****' etc

However, this is extremely slow as the index negates the function(or vice versa?). Is there a way to insert into a computed column using the COLLATE function and then index that column?

Thanks, I'm a year 1 IT apprentice so basically everything is new to me!
Aidan

Comment: Presumably you're using SQL Server, please Tag your database and its version

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `%` wildcard at the end of the `LIKE` expression:

```
WHERE [Code_Records] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN Like '[3]%'
```

Alternatively, you can use `Substring()` to get the first character and match that.

Comment: didn't appreciate the comment above. It's my first time asking a question here and I consistently see people being asked which version of SSMS they use. I copied and pasted the wrong characters, in my where clause it's: WHERE [Code_Records] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN Like '[3]____' But that's not what I wanted help with, it returns everything I need, but the performance is terrible, it's used in multiple procedures and it's slowing other people's queries down. I need to know if a computed column can be populated using COLLATE from another column in the table and indexed?